# scroll mysql table contents in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have a table in MySQL database like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|ID |Word | Meaning | Synonyms    |
-----------------------------------
|1  |abc  |xyxy     |abcxyxy      |
|2  |def  |yzyz     |defyzyz      |
|3  |ghi  |zxzx     |ghizxzx      |
-----------------------------------
```

The table have about 1500 rows. I want to display the contents of column "Word" in a scroll box and if I click on rows of that scroll box the meaning and synonyms should show. For example:

```
---------------------------------------
|abc          |^|                     |                                
|def          | |                     | 
|ghi          | |                     |
---------------------------------------
```

Here on the left side is the scroll box. Again the scroll box has a lot of items. Now if I click on "def" in the scroll box the page should look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|abc             |^| Meaning: yzyz        |                                
|def(Highlighted)| | Synonyms: defyzyz    | 
|ghi             | |                      |
-------------------------------------------
```

if clicked on "ghi" the page should look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|abc             |^| Meaning: zxzx        |                                
|def             | | Synonyms: ghizxzx    | 
|ghi(Highlighted)| |                      |
-------------------------------------------
```

How can I do this? An example would be appreciated as I am new in this.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as an Accepted Answer with the green check mark below the up and down arrows. If it solved your problem. That's how we roll on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the scroll bar by using the CSS which shows exactly in the @Jack answer. However, if you want to fetch the data from the MySQL then you'll need to use Ajax. You can run two MySQL query with PHP or any other server-side languages you prefer. One query will fetch all the ID and insert it using any custom HTML data attribute like this:

```
<li data-id="1"></li>
<li data-id="2"></li>
<li data-id="3"></li>
```

And on your second query you can fetch the data from the MySQL by using the ID when a particular item is clicked. You can send the Ajax request when it will be clicked.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    // Fetch the data-id value for particular item when clicked
    // Run an Ajax request to fetch the MySQL data
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mazedul Vai. I will let you know once I've tried it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div like this:

```
 <div class="container">
   <!-- mysql content -->
 </div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

Comment: this will show the scroll box. how to show relevant data when an item on the scroll box is clicked?

Comment: so you want you click on a row it shows the whole row

Comment: ok i see what you want

Comment: you mite want to use JS and PHP to do it

Comment: ok..but how? link to a tutorial/example to do this would be great as I am new to this and I couldn't find anything myself..

Comment: The design approach you are looking for is commonly referred to as "Master Details View". [Look at this example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/master-details) and http://demo.bootcards.org/contacts] (this one)